# Loading an typed dataset from an XML document

Tags: .net, xml, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I am unable to fill a typed dataset

```
Using reader as New StringReader(My.Resources.sampledata)
  typedDataset.ReadXML(reader)
  'typedDataset.WriteXML("c:\data.xml")
End Using
```

The above does not work. If I enable the commented line to write the results to file I get a 1K file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<testSchema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TestSchema.xsd" />
```

If I create a blank dataset liek this

```
Dim data as New DataSet
    Using reader as New StringReader(My.Resources.sampledata)
  data.ReadXML(reader)
  'data.WriteXML("c:\data.xml")
End Using
```

It writes data to the file. Which means that the dataset is loaded from the XML. The XML was created from a valid dataset

```
Dim ds as DataSet = Service.GetData(params)
ds.WriteXML(C:\sampledata.xml")
```

and then stored in the Resources file.

I also tried the options

```
1. Auto
2. ReadSchema
3. IgnoreSchema
4. InferSchema
```

With "InferSchema" I was able to add the XML but it created a second table.

All I want to do is load my Typed Dataset from an XML document which was created from dataset.WriteXML()

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

> ```
> Dim ds As New DataSet
> Using reader As New System.IO.StringReader(My.Resources.sampledata)
>       ds.ReadXml(reader)
>       typedDS.Load(ds.Tables(0).CreateDataReader(),
>                    LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,
>                    typedDS.MyTable)
>
> End Using
> ```

Comment: Thanks Saif.  You saved me a lot of headache :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write with schema included.

```
ds.WriteXml("TEST.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

edit:

or

```
ds.Tables[0].WriteXml("TEST.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
ds.Tables[0].ReadXml("TEST.xml");
```

or strongly typed datatable read/write

```
typedDataset.tableName.WriteXml("TEST.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
typedDataset.tableName.ReadXml("TEST.xml");
```

Comment: Are you saying that the XML which I am reading from (which was created from a dataset.WriteXML()) has to include the schema?

Comment: Yeah, I've run into it before. If you don't write the schema when you write it to disk, then it won't just read back in. I'm sure there is a way to give it the scheam on read or the infer, but it's just easiest to write the schema in the first place.

Comment: It loads this time but it ads a second table with the data and ignore the TypedTable created in the Visual Studio XSD dataset designer.

Comment: you understand that I am trying to load a dataset into a typeddataset...right?